# Placing different sizes images underneath each other

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, thumbnails

I am facing a problem while coding my own Wordpress theme. I have featured images of each blog posts displaying on my home page. I would like to make it look like a gallery. So I want the images to display under each other and next to each other, though they are different sizes. See the picture to see how far I've come:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/021QE.png)

So what I want to accomplish is, to display the blossom image under the New York one, and next to the 'c'est la vie' one. Is there any way to that?

I would really appreciate your help!
My HTML code:

```
<div class="post">

   <div class="outer-wrapper">
      <div class="imagefilter">
         <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php 
 the_post_thumbnail('mythumbnail');?></a>
       </div>

          <div class="text-wrapper">
          <span class="blogpost"><h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php 
          the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></span>
       </div>   
    </div>

  </div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 470px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
  float: left;}


 .text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
   display: table;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
   line-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;}
```

Comment: You'll need Javascript for that. You could, for example, use http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a masonry gallery style?
If so, this is more CSS related and here is an [nice example](https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE).

The main idea is using display: inline-block instead of float.
For example-

```
section {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  0.25rem;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
 background:  #efefef;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly the word I was looking for :) But for some reason the images are all underneath each other when I use inline-block

Comment: If the images are inside a container (a div maybe) then you need to add the display: inline-block to the wrapping div. If they are still one under another then there is probably a div with 100% width or without any CSS at all

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple to achieve using [CSS columns](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns). The GitHub project [darlanmendonca/masonry-css](https://github.com/darlanmendonca/masonry-css) does this with [these few lines of Sass](https://github.com/darlanmendonca/masonry-css/blob/master/src/masonry.scss):

```
.masonry {
  $spacing: 2px;
  column-gap: $spacing;
  padding: $spacing;
  columns: 2;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-sizing: border-box;

  @media (min-width: 511px) {columns: 3;}
  @media (min-width: 769px) {columns: 4;}
  @media (min-width: 1440px) {columns: 6;}

  .masonry-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: $spacing solid transparent;
  }
}
```

The result is something like the image below (taken from [darlanmendonca/masonry-css](https://github.com/darlanmendonca/masonry-css)).

[image]

[Here's his live demo](https://rawgit.com/darlanmendonca/masonry-css/master/dist/index.html). (The reflows you see on screen resize are due to the responsive breakpoints changing the number of columns.)

For the lazy, here's the pure-CSS compiled-and-beautified version of his Sass:

```
.masonry {
    -webkit-column-gap: 2px;
    -moz-column-gap: 2px;
    column-gap: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-sizing: border-box
}
@media (min-width: 511px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-columns: 3;
        -moz-columns: 3;
        columns: 3
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-columns: 4;
        -moz-columns: 4;
        columns: 4
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-columns: 6;
        -moz-columns: 6;
        columns: 6
    }
}
.masonry .masonry-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent
}
```

If you don't need it to be responsive, you can safely kill the media query bits and set your number of columns directly on `.masonry`.